# Runge-Kutta Implementation for a system of two differential equations

Tags: python, error-handling, numerical-methods, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I have the following system of differential equations:
[image]

And according to the paper they told I can solve it numerically by using RK 4th order.

As you can see, two last equations are coupled and I constructed a matrix (Probability) that associates xn and yn, where n = 1..(N- count of pairs, for instance, here N is equal 4) : vector([x1,x2,...,xn,y1,y2,...,yn])' = Probability.dot(vector([x1,x2,...,xn,y1,y2,...,yn])), where prime is time differentiation. But on the ither hand for each step I have additional term of sum (un * xn and the same for yn), it was the first problem I faced and didn't know how to deal with it.

I wrote a code and a lot of errors which I couldn't manage arose.

While I am trying to cope it by myself, I'll be very thankful for any help in it.

Above show you my code:

***Importing Libraries***

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.constants as sc
from scipy.sparse import diags
from scipy.integrate import ode
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import mlab
```

***Initial data and constants***

```
dimen_paramT0 = [0,0,0,0]
step = 0.00001

Mn = 1e-21      # mass of pairs
thau = 1e-15    # character time
wn_sqr = 1e-2   # to 10e-6 
wn_prime = 3e-2 # to 10e-5

n = 4 #count of repetition; forinstance 4
gamma_n = 3e-9 
Dn = 4e-2 
an = 4.45
alphaPrime_n = 0.13
Volt = 0.4
hn = 0
hn_nInc = 1.276 #hn,n+1
hn_nDec = 1.276 #hn,n-1
Un = thau * alphaPrime_n / Mn
ksi_n = an * Un
Omega_n = 2 * Dn * an * (thau ** 2) / (Mn * Un)
```

*** Constructing matrix for associations with dif/ eq/ for probability ***

```
k = np.array([hn_nInc*np.ones(n-1),hn*np.ones(n),hn_nDec*np.ones(n-1)])
offset = [-1,0,1]
Probability = diags(k,offset).toarray() # bn(tk)=xn(tk)+iyn(tk)


xt0_list = [0] * n
yt0_list = [0] * n
```

*** Right side of dif. eq. ***

```
# dimen_param = [un,vn,zn,vzn] [tn]
# x_list = [x1,...,xn] [tn]
# y_list = [y1,...,yn] [tn]

def fun(dimen_param, x_list, y_list):
    return dimen_param[1]

def fvn(dimen_param, x_list, y_list):
    return -(x_list[len(x_list)-1]**2 + y_list[len(y_list)-1]**2)- wn_prime*dimen_param[1] + Omega_n * (1-np.e ** (-ksi_n * dimen_param[0]))*np.e ** (-ksi_n * dimen_param[0])
    
def fzn(dimen_param, x_list, y_list):
    return dimen_param[3]

def fvzn(dimen_param, x_list, y_list):
    return -wn_prime * dimen_param[3]-(wn_sqr ** 2) * dimen_param[2] - 1

def fxn(dimen_param, x_list, y_list):
    return Probability.dot(y_list)

def fyn(dimen_param, x_list, y_list):
    return -Probability.dot(x_list)

#xv = [dimen_param, x_list, y_list]
def f(xv):
    
    k_d = xv[0:4]
    k_x = xv[4:4+len(xt0_list)]
    k_y = xv[4+len(xt0_list):4+len(xt0_list)+len(yt0_list)]

    return ([fun(k_d, k_x, k_y),fvn(k_d, k_x, k_y),fzn(k_d, k_x, k_y),fvzn(k_d, k_x, k_y),fxn(k_d, k_x, k_y),fyn(k_d, k_x, k_y)])
```

*** Realisation of Runge - Kutta method of 4th order ***

```
def RK4(f, dimen_paramT0, xt0_list, yt0_list):
    T = np.linspace(0, 1. / step, 1. / step +1)
    xvinit = np.concatenate([dimen_paramT0, xt0_list, yt0_list])
    xv = np.zeros( (len(T), len(xvinit)) )
    xv[0] = xvinit
    
    for i in range(int(1. / step)):
        k1 = f(xv[i])
        k2 = f(xv[i] + step/2.0*k1)
        k3 = f(xv[i] + step/2.0*k2)
        k4 = f(xv[i] + step*k3)
        xv[i+1] = xv[i] + step/6.0 *( k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)
    return T, xv
```

*** Running ***

```
print RK4(f, dimen_paramT0, xt0_list, yt0_list)
```

The problem at this moment is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-be8ed2e50d37> in <module>()
----> 1 RK4(f, dimen_paramT0, xt0_list, yt0_list)

<ipython-input-103-8c48cf5efe73> in RK4(f, dimen_paramT0, xt0_list, yt0_list)
      7     for i in range(int(1. / step)):
      8         k1 = f(xv[i])
----> 9         k2 = f(xv[i] + step/2.0*k1)
     10         k3 = f(xv[i] + step/2.0*k2)
     11         k4 = f(xv[i] + step*k3)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Comment: Is `k1` on the indicated line supposed to be a numpy array perhaps? Regular python lists and tuples don't support element-wise math operations.

Comment: k1 as others is a vector of coefficients

Comment: well... FHTMitchell seems to have beat me to a full answer.

Comment: @Aaron :) // OP, I don't understand why you're going through all this trouble when you already have imported scipy.integrate.ode. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I am not familiar with this library as weel as need, so you see the result of it

Comment: @kitsune_breeze I just want to point out a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42840933/3220135) in case you're interested... It concerns speeding up the calculation of the runge-kutta method using `numba` and just-in-time compilation.

Comment: The error message says it: "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'", hence this multiplication doesn't do what you think.

Answer (score 3):

`k1` is a python `list`, where multiply means "repeat", so

```
[1,2] * 3 == [1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

Obviously this doesn't make sense for floats

```
[1,2,3]*2.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-7d3451361a53> in <module>()
----> 1 [1,2,3]*2.0

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

You want the vector behaviour of `numpy.ndarray` where

```
np.array([1,2])*2.0 == np.array([2.0, 4.0])
```

so make sure that the return statement of `f` is:

```
return np.asarray([
    fun(k_d, k_x, k_y),
    fvn(k_d, k_x, k_y),
    fzn(k_d, k_x, k_y),
    fvzn(k_d, k_x, k_y),
    fxn(k_d, k_x, k_y),
    fyn(k_d, k_x, k_y)
])
```

---

For the record, `scipy` has an [RK4 solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html#scipy.integrate.RK45) already, no need to implement your own.

Comment: RK45 is the embedded Dormand-Prince order 4/5 method with adapted step size, not the fixed-step classical 4th order method. Apart from that you are correct in that using RK45 will almost always give better results faster.

Comment: It was so in the reason of the first operating it in applied calculus :)